# sort array with true values first

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can I sort an array so all objects with a value of `true` for the key `can_friend` will be first in the array?

```
var people = [{can_friend: true}, {can_friend: false}, {can_friend: true}]
```

would get sorted to

```
var desired_result = [{can_friend: true}, {can_friend: true}, {can_friend: false}]
```

Comment: Can you post the code showing what you have tried?

Comment: @MT0 for a tiny question like that posting his attempts are boring.  Question is fine.  Also this is Javascript so gloves are off.

Comment: @MK. fine - but I prefer to see some attempt at a solution. (Although I'll give kudos for putting the desired results there - which is more than many)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a standard `sort` using `can_friend` as criterion and the fact that booleans convert to `1` and `0` on subtraction:

```
people.sort(function (a, b) { return b.can_friend - a.can_friend; });
```

Comment: you are a terrible person.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to go take a shower... But hey, if you're stuck with a dynamically typed language, **use the type system, Luke!**

Comment: HAHAHA... I'm watching Star Wars right now... that's hilarious.

Comment: The dark side of the Force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be…unnatural.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is tagged with `underscore.js`, here's a solution using it:

```
var sorted = _.sortBy( people, function(element){ return element.can_friend ? 0 : 1; } );
```

or shorter:

```
var sorted = _.sortBy( people, function(e){ return !e.can_friend; } );
```

or using ES6 arrow function syntax:

```
var sorted = _.sortBy( people, e=>!e.can_friend );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
people.sort(function(val1, val2) {
  if (val1.can_friend && !val2.can_friend) return -1;
  else if (!val1.can_friend && val2.can_friend) return 1;
  else return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in plain JS, which works for the situation perfectly:

```
people.sort(function(item) {
  return !item.can_friend;
});
```

Comment: you are also a terrible person (especially if this actually works)

Comment: @ElG If it does, it's a fluke.

Comment: I just created a fiddle... and tested it... I was surprised, too

Comment: I don't know... I think it does... if can_friend is true, it will return 0, if it's false it will return 1... which will put it after all of the 0s... it really doesn't matter what the other value of the sort function is.

Comment: @ElG This only ever returns `0` or `1`, while negative values must also be returned. Some `sort` implementations seem to require it. This sort reproducibly fails in Safari.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81980/discussion-between-el-guapo-and-deceze).